# How to merge two hashes without losing values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hashes like these.

```
a = {foo: {first: 1}, bar: {first: 2}}
b = {foo: {second: 3}, bar: {second: 4}}
```

And I expected as a result of `a.merge b` like this.

```
{foo: {first: 1, second: 3}, bar: {first: 2, second: 4}}
```

But `a.merge b` returns `{:foo=>{:second=>3}, :bar=>{:second=>4}}`.

How can I merge two hashes without losing values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the format of your hash would always look like you specified the below would work:

```
a = {foo: {first: 1}, bar: {first: 2}}
b = {foo: {second: 3}, bar: {second: 4}}
a.each_with_object(b) { |(k,v),x| x[k].merge!(v) }
# => {:foo=>{:second=>3, :first=>1}, :bar=>{:second=>4, :first=>2}}
```

Otherwise use `ActiveSupport`'s [`deep_merge!`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge!)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the form of [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that takes a block that determines the value associated with every key that is present in both hashes.

**Code**

```
def merge_em(a,b)    
  a.merge(b) { |k,va,vb| va.merge(vb) }
end
```

**Example**

```
a = {foo: {first:  1}, bar: {first:  2}}
b = {foo: {second: 3}, bar: {second: 4}}

merge_em(a,b)
  #=> {:foo=>{:first=>1, :second=>3}, :bar=>{:first=>2, :second=>4}}
```

**Explanation**

Here the block variables are as follows:

```
`k` : the key
`va`: the value for key `k` in the merged hash (`a`)
`vb`: the value for key `k` in the hash being merged (`b`)
```

We want the value for key `k` to be simply:

```
va.merge(vb)
```